Header file is in the wrong location
I wanted to include xf86drmMode.h in my c code, but when I did it says there was an error in the header file as it couldn't find drm.h. It's because there is no drm.h on my system, there's only libdrm/drm.h. What am I meant to do? Edit the header? I mean I guess I could but would that cause issues in my system?
I tried using sudo pacman -Syu linux-headers libdrm but nothing changed. Theres no straight up drm package either to install.
> ls /usr/include | grep "drm"
libdrm                                                                           
xf86drm.h
xf86drmMode.h

> ls /usr/include/libdrm                                                                                                 
amdgpu_drm.h  drm_mode.h   intel_bufmgr.h  msm_drm.h      r128_drm.h       radeon_bo_int.h  radeon_drm.h      tegra_drm.h    vmwgfx_drm.h
amdgpu.h      drm_sarea.h  intel_debug.h   nouveau        r600_pci_ids.h   radeon_cs_gem.h  radeon_surface.h  vc4_drm.h
drm_fourcc.h  i915_drm.h   mach64_drm.h    nouveau_drm.h  radeon_bo_gem.h  radeon_cs.h      savage_drm.h      via_drm.h
drm.h         intel_aub.h  mga_drm.h       qxl_drm.h      radeon_bo.h      radeon_cs_int.h  sis_drm.h         virtgpu_drm.h


Tell the compiler where to look with -I/usr/include/libdrm

Archlinux, in general provides packages from upstream without modification. So you can rely on the header being in the same location the authors put it. Simply look at where the libdrm headers are placed, e.g. pacman -Ql libdrm | grep include. Other than libsync.h, xf86drm.h and xf86drmMode.h all headers from the package are installed in /usr/include/libdrm/.


What am I meant to do?

Add  /usr/include/libdrm   to compiler include search path.
Typically a build system is used. Looking at the output of pacman -Ql libdrm I see pkgconfig. Use:
gcc $(pkgconf --cflags --libs libdrm)

to compile programs. If you check pkgconf --cflags --libs libdrm you'll see it adds -I/usr/include/libdrm to compile include search paths.

Edit the header?

No.

would that cause issues in my system?

Yes.
